# Validate delimiter separated values using JOI

Tags: validation, joi

I have a use case where I need to validate a set of values separated by | .

I followed https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/570 but it throws a number of errors. 
Is there any way I can do this?

Example- AA|BB|CC|DD

Now, I need to validate that all of the values (AA, BB, CC, DD) are strings.

I believe I can't use regex as it would validate just the first value.

Also, there are a number of other validations in my code, so I don't wish to loop the validation process.

Please let me know if I'm unclear. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR:

```js
const Joi = require('joi').extend(joi => ({
  base: joi.array(),
  coerce: (value, helpers) => ({
    value: value.split ? value.split('|') : value,
  }),
  type: 'versionArray',
}))
```

The `.extend` [function signature has changed](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/c451ef5575c40622ea6bd64810a79ea10e5cb020/lib/index.d.ts#L1884-L1900) since that comment was written; the `name` property has been removed and the `CoerceFunction` should return an object with `value` as the property.

```sh
> Joi.versionArray().validate('AA|BB|CC|DD')
{ value: [ 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD' ] }
> Joi.versionArray().validate('AA|BB,CC|DD')
{ value: [ 'AA', 'BB,CC', 'DD' ] }
```

From here on, you can use the `.items(...)` function to validate each of the strings in the returned array:

```sh
> const regex = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z]+$') // every character must be a-z or A-Z 
undefined

> Joi.versionArray().items(Joi.string().regex(regex)).validate('AA|BB|CC|DD')
{ value: [ 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD' ] }

> Joi.versionArray().items(Joi.string().regex(regex)).validate('AA|BB|CC|00')
{ value: [ 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', '00' ],
  error:
   { ValidationError: "[3]" with value "00" fails to match the required pattern: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/ _original: 'AA|BB|CC|00', details: [ [Object] ] } }

> Joi.versionArray().items(Joi.string().regex(regex)).validate('AA|BB,CC|DD')
{ value: [ 'AA', 'BB,CC', 'DD' ],
  error:
   { ValidationError: "[1]" with value "BB,CC" fails to match the required pattern: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/ _original: 'AA|BB,CC|DD', details: [ [Object] ] } }
```